# add viewcontroller to uiwindow addsubview

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow, addsubview

//I am Using.

```
CalVC *cal = [[CalVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalVC" bundle:nil];
cal.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:cal.view];
```

It is working and The CalVC appear and i show a calculator in CalVc but when it appear by this method the buttons of calculator not working and show me error //exc_bad_access code=exc_i386_gpflt ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CalVC was released. So you have to define a property and keep it in .h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalVC * _cal;
```

in .m file:

`_cal = [[CalVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalVC" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Thanx anhtu it didnt crash now thanx

Comment: and do you know how to remove this uiwindow from another view

Comment: [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
i used it to rmove but it still appear on screen but when i click on any button it crashed.

Comment: @vivekpadaya not sure about 'this uiwindow' means. But for remove _cal(CalVC): [_cal.view removeFromSuperView];

Answer (score 0):

Just Create global reference of `CalVC *cal` as a property . Here your view is deallocating due to local reference .

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CalVC * _cal;
```